# Удаление всех символов после пробела в отдельной колонке pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Не могу понять, как удалить все символы после первого пробела в столбце pandas.

Вот пример кода:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("log.txt", delimiter=";", names=["Date","Recipe","int"])
df.iloc[0].str.split("_")[0]
print(df)
```

В файле log.txt:

```
01.01.2001 10:10:10 ; 110er Nest hol ; 112
```

Нужно удалить в столбце `Recipe` все после `110er`.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно применить метод apply к столбцу:

```
df['Recipe'] = df['Recipe'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])
```

Это разобьет каждый элемент столбца по пробелам на список и вернет первый элемент этого списка(первое слово), и заменит изначальное значение на этот первый элемент.

Comment: Благодарю, помогло

Answer (score 3):

Для общего развития - воспользуйтесь аксессорами `str`:

```
df["Recipe"] = df["Recipe"].str.split().str[0]
```

**Замечание**: несмотря на то, что этот код короче кода с `apply` и не привлекает к обработке данных безымянную функцию, на больших датасетах он будет *менее эффективен*, чем код с использованием apply по очевидным причинам использования двойного аксессора.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с регуляркой

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['01.01.2001 10:10:10', '110er Nest hol ', 112]], columns=["Date", "Recipe", "int"])
df.Recipe = df.Recipe.str.replace(' .*', '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

```
                  Date Recipe  int
0  01.01.2001 10:10:10  110er  112
```